# 5V output on the Zero W

Tags: pi-zero-w

I am trying to power a data line which asks 5 volts, but my raspberry pi zero only offers 5v power, and 3.3v on the data pins. If I were to simply use a transistor like the 2N2222 with the 5V power supply as the collector, the 3.3V data pin as the base, and use the emitter pin to supply the signal to the data line of my load, would there be any problematic disturbances in the signal? If so, what is a better product to use?

Comment: Please help yourself and [learn to use the schematic tool.](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2074/how-do-i-add-a-schematic-to-my-question)

Answer (score 2):

You **might** be better off using a [level shifter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_shifter). It's hard to say for sure because you've not provided any details in your question. You can [buy a level shifter](https://www.sparkfun.com/categories/361), or you can [build a level shifter](https://www.okdo.com/project/level-shifting/).

All of this information (and more) is available for the cost of an [Internet search.](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=level+shifter&t=ffnt&ia=web)

Answer (score 0):

If you use an emitter follower you will get 3.3V output.

What you describe will just produce a hot transistor.

No one can say "what is a better product to use?" because you haven't provided any data.

Comment: I don't think an emitter follower will have 3.3V on the emitter with 3.3V on the base. The highest voltage you could expect is about 2.7V at the emitter.